Does this network transformation have a name?
The authors of this paper analyse the following transformation on graphs. For any graph $G$, the graph $\tilde G$ is produced by replacing all links in $G$ by nodes. Two nodes in $\tilde G$ are connected by a link if the corresponding links in $G$ connect to a common node. This seems like a reasonably natural construction, but I havent been able to find any sources which look at the properties of this transformation. Does anyone know if it has a name/know of any references where it appears?
Below is a picture of an example of the transformation.


Yes! This is called the line graph of $G$.
